# 2-coloring of nodes in a network graph

Tags: networking, graph, graph-coloring

I am looking for a good algorithm to perform 2-coloring on a given network graph (i.e., painting each node in the network in one of two colors such that no pair of nodes directly connected by an edge have the same color). In case of conflicts, the algorithm should remove nodes from the network, but minimize the number of removed nodes. Does anyone know if such an algorithm is available (an implementation in Python or R would be a great bonus).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a BFS at any node alternating between active colors in each iteration. color nodes not yet visited. Repeat for every connected component.

If you reach a node `u` that has been visited and is colored in the color not currently active, the graph is not 2-colorable.

An optimal node removal cannot be efficiently implemented. Consider a wheel with at least 3 spokes as a subgraph ie. a hub node connected to each node of a cycle of even length >= 4. The minimum number of nodes to remove in order to allow for 2-coloring is 1 and there is exactly 1 solution to achieve this: removing the hub.

So wheel detection is a prerequisite for optimal sparsification.

However, [this paper](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1452-8630/2014/1452-86301300023D.pdf) proves that wheel detection is np-complete.